# Define custom fields in log4j.properties file?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

For e.g. I have my own Log4j.property file with my own defined appender

I want to use some custom fields in the appender like URL, APP_ID, etc.

Is something of these sort possible.

```
Log4j.URL=http://google.com
Log4j.APP_ID="Hello"
```

Then I need to fetch these property file in code.And get values of URL ,APP_ID etc.

Below is my own property file.

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG
log4j.logger.log=DEBUG,LOG_APPENDER

log4j.additivity.log=false

#LOG_APPENDER 
log4j.appender.LOG_APPENDER=com.FIVE.logger.Log4jAppender
log4j.appender.LOG_APPENDER.Threshold=INFO
```